# Fixed points of $g$?

Tags: nonlinear-system

Consider the functions $f(x) = 1 - \frac{1}{2x}$

and $g(x) = 2x(1-x)$

How many roots does $f$ have? Are the roots of $f$ fixed-points of $G$ are there more fixed points of $g$ than roots of $f$?

---

Confused as to how to answer this question

The roots of $f$ is $1 = \frac{1}{2x} \implies x = \frac{1}{2}$

Now how do I find the fixed points of $G$?

Comment: You're looking for $x_0$ such that $g(x_0) = x_0$.  Write that condition down and do some substitutions.

Comment: I'm looking at my notes about fixed point I have this https://gyazo.com/37985606463d7c6173a92dd7cc968f0a but I'm unsure how to apply any of that.

Comment: I told you how.  Write down $g(x_0) = x_0$ and solve for $x_0$.

Comment: $g(1/2) = 2 \cdot (1 - \frac{1}{2}) = \frac{1}{2}$ therefore the root of $f(x)$ is a fix point of $g$? Third part I still don't understand.

Comment: Edit: last comment was a mistake.  But all you have to do is count the roots of $f$ and the fixed points of $g$.  If you really want to, try to figure out the relationship between $f$ and $g$ (I assumed there was none).

Comment: $2x(1-x)=x \Leftrightarrow x (2(1-x) -1) = 0 \Leftrightarrow x (1-2x) = 0 \cdots$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$2x(1-x)=x$ implies $x=0$ or $2(1-x)=1$ so $x=0$ or $x =\frac  1 2$.